# Accessibilty for screen reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

How to make part of a div not visible for a screen reader using jquery?
i was trying to implement readmore readless functionality on certain text but i am facing issues with screen reader but i have to allow accessibilty here.
here is my code where i will be showing a part of my div based on line count:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var divHeight,l=3;
 $('.comment').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this),divHeight;
 var $content = $this.find(".text-content"),
   lineHeight= $content.css('line-height');
   divHeight= ((parseInt(l)+3)*parseInt(lineHeight))+"px";
   if($content.hasClass("short-text")){
      $content.css("height","auto");
   }
   else{
    $content.addClass("short-text");
    $content.css("overflow","hidden");
    $content.css("height",divHeight);
    $content.on("focus",function(){
      $(this).attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
    })
   }
   html='<p class="'+'para'+'"><a href="#" class="morelink morelinkStyle">' + 'more' + '</a></p></span>';
   $this.append(html);
 });
 $(".morelink").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    $elem=$this.parents().find(".text-content");
    if ($elem.hasClass("short-text")) {
        $elem.removeClass("short-text");
        $this.html('less');
        divHeight = $elem.height();
        $elem.css("height","auto");
    } else {
        $elem.addClass("short-text");
        $elem.on("focus",function(){
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).css("border","2px solid red");
      $(this).attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
       })
        $this.html('more');
        $elem.css("height",divHeight);
        $elem.css("overflow","hidden");
    }
    return false;
    });
```

HTML being:

```
<div class="comment">
<article class="text-content">
   <h3>Bedspreads</h3>
<p>Bedspreads add an elegant, ornamental look to any <a href="/store/category/bedding/10504/">bedroom</a>. They may just sit atop your bed but the right spread can pull an entire room together and create a central focal point to your bedroom. That's why Bed Bath &amp; Beyond offers a large array of bedspreads and comforters to help you find exactly what you are looking for. Wow any visitor or guest with a beautiful,</p> <p>1st para -vibrant floral pattern that brightens up any room, create a bold look with solid colors and modern styling or bring in a traditional design with classic chenille patterns. Turn your room into a viewing experience today with our ever-growing selection.Ut enim ad minim veniam,
</p>
<p>2nd para-vibrant floral pattern that brightens up any room, create a bold look with solid colors and modern styling or bring in a traditional design with classic chenille patterns. Turn your room into a viewing experience today with our ever-growing selection.Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: here i have taken lines to be 3 initially in variable l

Comment: i have given line-height to elements as well

Answer (score 0):

Editing the height & overflow properties of the div will not hide the content from a screenreader. You need to use display:none in your short-text class. (Also, it is easier to write the class in your CSS and just use jquery to add/remove the class name).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months ago, I was tasked with solving the same problem of implementing "Read More" / "Read Less" links while maintaining WCAG 2.0 accessibility.

If you aren't opposed to using Bootstrap and jQuery, I have a pretty good solution. The bootstrap `collapse` class makes it possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/rmatnwrm/